# How to return a concatenated string from `String` fields?

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a method of an object that returns a combination of `String` fields of that object.  I have tried several approaches, as you can see in the example code, and in each case I am getting errors shown below including

- expected `&str`, found struct `std::string::String`
- `s` is borrowed here
- cannot return value referencing local variable `s`

```rust
struct Person {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    age: u8,
}
// BEHAVIOR OF CLASS
impl Person {
    fn full_name(&self) -> &str {
        let s = format!("{} {}", self.first_name, self.last_name);

        // temporary, test
        println!("** test, s: {}", s);

        // how to return the 's' value?

        // try 1. expected `&str`, found struct `std::string::String`
        // s
        // try 2. `s` is borrowed here
        // s.as_str()
        // try 3. cannot return value referencing local variable `s`
        // &s[..]
        // try 4. cannot return value referencing local variable `s`
        // &*s

        // then escape
        "?"
    }

    // works fine
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        match self.age {
            0..=12 => "Clild",
            13..=17 => "Teenager",
            _ => "Adult",
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Laboratory");

    let p = Person {
        first_name: String::from("Alexandra"),
        last_name: String::from("Ansley"),
        age: 25,
    };

    println!("Full Name   : {}", p.full_name());
    println!("Description : {}", p.description());
}
```

How can I write this method without these errors?

Comment: What you try to do is a classic dangling pointer mistake, and Rust rightfully prevents you from doing it. You create a `String` object, and try to return a reference to it. **But**, the `String` object will be destroyed immediately after the function ends. You better return the object itself, not a reference. Return `String` type, and return it as just `s`

Comment: An answer that took me 2 hours to skate. But I wasted no time and learned my lesson. -> String ... TXS

Answer (score 1):

Explanation for Trial 1:

```rust
fn full_name(&self) -> &str {
        // format macro returns a String
        let s = format!("{} {}", self.first_name, self.last_name);        
        s // Error: return type and given type doesn't match 
    }
```

Explanation for Trial 2:

```rust
fn full_name(&self) -> &str {
        let s = format!("{} {}", self.first_name, self.last_name); // owned value     
        let s_str = s.as_str() // reference to s

        s_str
    } // s is dropped here

// s_str is now a dangling pointer, so it is rightly refused by the borrow checker
```

Explanation for Trial 3:

```rust
fn full_name(&self) -> &str {
        let s = format!("{} {}", self.first_name, self.last_name); // owned value     
        let s_str = &s[...] // is equivalent to s.as_str()

        s_str // reference to s
    } // s is dropped here

// s_str is now a dangling pointer, so it is rightly refused by the borrow checker
```

Explanation for Trial 4:

```rust
impl Person {
    fn full_name(&self) -> String {
        let s = format!("{} {}", self.first_name, self.last_name);
        
        let s_str = &*s // is equivalent to &*std::ops::Deref(&s), which is of type &str 
        // see https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-dereference-operator

        s_str  // reference to s 
    }  // s is dropped here
}

// s_str is now a dangling pointer, so it is rightly refused by the borrow checker
```

You need to return a `String` instead of `&str` since:

- You can't return reference to an owned value created inside a function definition block without creating a dangling pointer.
- and you can't concatenate two `&str` together without allocating both of them into a `String`, because `&str` needs to be contiguous memory [(see docs)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html?highlight=contiguous#slice)

Answer (score 0):

(Given your comments, I think you already know everything here. I'm just writing for later searchers.)

```
fn full_name(&self) -> &str { ... }
```

The most important fact about this signature is that it must return a reference to *existing* memory. It can't create any new thing. The whole point of `&str` is "a pointer to something that will exist for at least as long as you have this reference."

So this would be fine if there were a property on this struct that held onto `full_name`. But if the function constructs "the full name," this is impossible.

The most natural thing to do here is return `String` (and that's my recommendation). That's an owned value, so you can create it in the function and transfer it to the caller.

Another approach would be to have a `full_name` property that started empty, and was lazily filled in when requested and returned as a `&str`, with the promise that it would live as long as the struct.